# Java - Zoom / 3D Data Visualization Libraries

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, processing, data-visualization

What are the best libraries/frameworks for doing 3D and/or Zoom interfaces in Java?
I'd like to be able to do some prototyping of creating new types of interfaces for navigating within data and representing object graphs/relationships.

Low and no cost options are better. Open Source is also a plus.

**UPDATE**:
The higher level the api the better. Ideally I could set some properties (color, shape, etc) on my virtual object, register it with the visualization environment/engine, hook in callback functions...for example when a user hovers, clicks or double clicks on an object my code would get kicked off, and the visualization environment would handle the rest. So the rendering of the objects, navigation, zoom, user interaction would all be handled by the engine. Tall order probably, but this seems like it could exist as a reusable/generic tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java3D is a pretty good 3d visualization in library. OpenGL is a standard 3d graphics library and JOGL is a port to Java.

Comment: +1 - Java3D or OpenGL is a good start. Are there any libraries or frameworks that would help with the "update" part of my question or the comment to Sam.

Comment: You may want to look into MouseBehavior in Java3D. Java3D is a higher level API so if you are looking for higher level, I'd suggest Java3D instead of JOGL.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done more than play with it, but you may want to look into [processing](http://www.processing.org/). You could build some virtual objects, then pan around it with the mouse.

Comment: Processing looked like an option. +1 But I was hoping to work at a slightly higher level. Was hoping someone or group had already worked on resuable objects (ex 3D but click-able, linkable, drag-able, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

You might try [JMonkeyEngine](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/home/).  It's higher level than Java3D and JOGL.